# Proper use of Shell function when path contains spaces

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to open an image from Excel-VBA using the `Shell` function.
The first line of code works, but I do not want it to open in Paint. I want it to open in Windows Live Photo Gallery as the second line of code suggests, but this line does not work. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
Shell("mspaint.exe C:\test\Data_Sample\Figures\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".jpeg")
Shell ("WLXPhotoGallery.exe C:\test\Data_Sample\Figures\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".jpeg")
```

**EDIT**
As BK201 suggested, I tried writing the full path to the WLXPhotoGallery executable; although this does open Windows Live Photo Gallery, it doesn't open the image I need. Why?

```
PGallery = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe"
Pic = "C:\test\Data_Sample\Figures\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".jpg"
Shell (PGallery & " " & Pic)
```

Comment: Does it work if you type this command at the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path of Windows Live Photo Gallery. This is because `mspaint.exe` can be found in `system32`, which is why it can be called without the path being written out. This is not the case with WLXPG.

```
Sub OpenPic()

PGallery = "C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe"
Pic = 'insert path here of picture/photo
Shell (PGallery & " " & Pic)

End Sub
```

This is untested, so modify as necessary.

Comment: i have alter the codes to the path in my computer and although it does open windows live photo gallery ,it doesn't open the image i need.

Comment: Try the old way of declaring the whole paths inside the Shell function. I don't usually use Shell so I don't know if declared strings can be passed to it. Basically, please try: `Shell("C:\Program Files... C:\test\Data_Sample\Figures\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".jpg")`. :)

Comment: The only other option I can think of here is to use the `ShellExecute` function. But that entails using/doing a variety of things, including getting the window handle of Windows Live Photo Gallery, which I don't have in my PC so I can't test.

Comment: @BK201: Yes, strings can be passed to `Shell`. What you wrote is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're missing `"` quotes. Surround your paths in `"` quotes otherwise Windows may not properly interpret paths containing spaces. Since they're inside a string, you actually have to write quotes like this `""`. Result:

```
PGallery = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe"""
Pic = """C:\test\Data_Sample\Figures\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".jpg"""
Shell (PGallery & " " & Pic)
```